# Running npm run start opens a file and not the script specified

Tags: angular, powershell, npm, visual-studio-code

I have upgraded my angular app to version 8.1 and as usual I would like to start the development server by running the npm start script as a VS Code task with `CTRL+P` and typing `task start`.

Also when running `npm run start` form powershell it immediately terminates and requests to opens the ng entry script file with the following content.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
'use strict';

// Provide a title to the process in `ps`.
// Due to an obscure Mac bug, do not start this title with any symbol.
try {
  process.title = 'ng ' + Array.from(process.argv).slice(2).join(' ');
} catch(_) {
  // If an error happened above, use the most basic title.
  process.title = 'ng';
}

// Some older versions of Node do not support let or const.
var version = process.version.substr(1).split('.');
if (Number(version[0]) < 10 || (Number(version[0]) === 10 && Number(version[1]) < 9)) {
  process.stderr.write(
    'You are running version ' + process.version + ' of Node.js, which is not supported by Angular CLI 8.0+.\n' +
    'The official Node.js version that is supported is 10.9 or greater.\n\n' +
    'Please visit https://nodejs.org/en/ to find instructions on how to update Node.js.\n'
  );

  process.exit(3);
}

require('../lib/init');
```

When running the command `ng serve` from powershell everything works fine.  npm is also configured to use powershell:

```
script-shell = "C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe"
shell = "C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe"
```

Why would it open a script instead of executing it?

Comment: What are the file permissions of the script? (It should be marked as executable)

Comment: Btw, you can run `npm start` instead of `npm run start`.

Comment: Thanks @Edric, your question regarding the file permissions made me think.  The issue was that I installed the dependencies in bash (wsl) and then later switched to powershell.  I jsut reinstalled `@angular/cli` with powershell and everything worked as expected!